# unable to open data base on windows start up Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open my app in windows start up but in windows start up it is giving an error
and saying unable to open the data base, i used a sqlite database when the app start by user it is working fine and the app can find the database but in windows startup it cant 
and iam geting the unable to open database

here is the code i used for db connection string:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=.\\notes_db.db;");
```

and the windows startup code:

```
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

if you know how i can get it, please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set your current directory to be your application's folder.

Something like this, untested:

```
Enviorment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetPath(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

When the registry starts your application. It uses system32 as the current directory.

Comment: i solved my problem thanks for your answer

Comment: i got the location of my app and set it to the connection string and it is worked